# Android: Use "sp" not for text size, but element dimensions?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, accessibility

I have a fixed-width element. It contains text. I want the text to not break or be clipped when the user increases their system-wide font-size. Can I use "sp" to declare the element width so that the element is wider when the system-wide font size is increased? Or are "sp" meant only for text sizes?

[image]

Some background: I considered other options but decided against them:

- [AutoSizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview), but the element in question in repeated multiple times on the screen and I would like to have consistent font sizes. Using Autosizes could lead to varying font sizes.
- Allow the element to grow when the content is longer. But again, the element is repeated multiple times and I'd like to have a consistent width.

Comment: You can use sp anywhere a size is used. Whether you'll like the result is another matter.  I wouldn't expect this to behave the way you want it to.  Sp is really only promised to work for height-  there's no rule that fonts scale proportionally in width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sp` for any sizes. But you have to be careful since `sp` can be scaled almost about twice the normal size and it might make your design ugly.

You can also use `dp` for your text sizes. It would mean that the texts will not be big enough for users that changed the font size in phone settings.

I think you should consult with your designers about this to come up with a solution.